# Decimal display in SELECT, when length is coming from the source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My super simplified example would look like this:

```
create table #cucu(nr decimal(18,6), L int)
insert into #cucu(nr, L) values (12.12, 2)
insert into #cucu(nr, L) values (1.1, 3)
insert into #cucu(nr, L) values (2.2222, 4)
select nr, l/*, CONVERT(decimal(18,L), nr) AS YeahRight*/ from #cucu
drop table #cucu
```

I would like to add something like the commented section, which **obviously does not work**. (Notice the **L** in the comment)

I need to select data from the **nr** column with a specific decimal length, which can be different on every row.

My best idea would be to add a SQL function for the **YeahRight** column, but because of performance, I thought I would ask if there is anything simpler than that.

Comment: Either do the formatting in your application layer *(which is **much** more recommended from a software-engineering perspective; formatting rarely belongs in a data-layer)* or format the value as a string.

Comment: @Ash This won't work for very simple reason. Column has to have specific datatype. In your scenario it would have different datatype across multiple rows. Of course you could use approach proposed in answer, but it will be string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`str()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
select nr, str(nr, 18, L)
```

Two cautions.  First, the returned value is a string.  That makes sense, because you care about formatting.  Second, the string will be padded with spaces, but these can be trimmed out.

Comment: I like this one !